# Changing the return object while using Spring Actuators?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn the use of Actuators, and I am making use of the /health endpoint offered by Spring. Following this blog, http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators, I wrote my custom HealthIndicator (can paste the implementation if needed). But the response I get is similar to this:

```
{
    "status" : "DOWN",
    "myHealthCheck" : {
        "status" : "DOWN",
        "Error Code" : 1,
        "Description" : "You custom MyHealthCheck endpoint is down"
     },
     "diskSpace" : {
         "status" : "UP",
         "free" : 209047318528,
         "threshold" : 10485760
     }
}
```

What I want is the following response:

```
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "dependencies": {
        "myHealthCheck": {
            "status": "DOWN",
            "Error Code": 1,
            "Description": "You custom MyHealthCheck endpoint is down"
        }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP",
        "free": 209047318528,
        "threshold": 10485760
    }
}
```

That is, I want the response of all my custom health indicators to be inside the Key called "dependencies". Is there any way I can modify the Spring Actuator for this?